# How to add tags to image uploaded to imgur api from python?

Tags: python, imgur

I am programming a bot so that I can upload local images to my Imgur account, but I *also* want to add tags of each image from Python

Here is my code:

```py
import requests
import base64

headers1 = {'Authorization': 'Bearer Xxxx',}
params = {
        'title':f'uwu',
        'description':'hello',
        'name':'Hey',
        'add_tags':'Fortnite',

        'image': base64.b64encode(open('cosmetico.png', 'rb').read())}
r = requests.post(f'https://api.imgur.com/3/image', headers=headers1, data=params)
data = r.json()["data"]["link"]
id = r.json()["data"]["id"]
```

I have tried to add `add_tags` or `tags` but none work.

I would like to be able to add the tags:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaSoE.png]

But I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Could you add a reference to the api documentation that says you can add tags this way? I do not see the add_tags attribute here https://apidocs.imgur.com/#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139

Comment: @yan5487 Did you find out any more information about this? I've been looking for a way to tag images uploaded from an app but I cant see anything on the API.

Comment: as according to api u can't tag just images but u can tag gallery. check here https://apidocs.imgur.com/#933424d1-e50f-4907-b1a1-d9fc4141a965